# Is it possible to integrate Kendo Grid with Azure Table / Shared Access Signature?

Tags: wcf, azure, kendo-grid, odata, azure-table-storage

I'm exploring different ways to get a Kendo grid to interact with Azure tables. I could have a front-end for Azure Table and expose the data using WCF/SignalR/OData, etc.

Or I can directly expose Azure Table with KendoUI over OData with shared access signatures.

I did a lot of searching, but I didn't see much out there with this combination.  What is the viability of this integration  ?

Comment: Do you have any updates about this thread?

Answer (score 1):

> I did a lot of searching, but I didn't see much out there with this combination. What is the viability of this integration ?

Base on my understanding,  we could do that. According to the Kendo Grid [official document](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/datasource/crud#schema) and demo examples, it allows us to get the  grid data source from the http request.

```
 var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: function (e) {
            // on success
            e.success(sampleData);
            // on failure
            //e.error("XHR response", "status code", "error message");
        }
    }
}
```

> it can even make a custom Ajax request and then pass the response.

So  we can use the Azure table REST API  to get table entities for the dataSource. More info about query azure table REST API please refer to [Query Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/query-entities) document. More Azure table REST API please refer to [Table Service REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/table-service-rest-api) document.

Related Info :

[Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services) Support for the Azure Storage Services

We can set that  easily from the azure portal to support CROS

[image]

Comment: So no to OData .... with some kind of extension to handle best practices like load balanced partition keys, IQuerable, filters, or alternative indexes for sorted data?

Comment: In the **URI Parameters** section of [REST API document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/query-entities) mentions that 'URI Parameters
The Query Entities operation supports the query options defined by the OData Protocol Specification'.